# How to call a function from controller to service in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Here is the code..

**Service:**

```
self.getNewCourses = function() {
      return "temp variable";
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$mmCourses.getNewCourses().then(function(data) {
    $scope.names = data;

    alert($scope.names);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`getNewCourses` function in your service is just returning a `string` and **NOT a promise**. Instead of doing `.then` on it , use it like below :

```
  $scope.names = $mmCourses.getNewCourses();

  console.log($scope.names);
```

Make sure you are returning the object **self** from the service and **$mmCourses** is injected in the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

First create a `service`, then inject in `controller` then use `function` using `yourService.yourFunctionName()...`.

See [icoxfog417's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/icoxfog417/DG24c/)

Hope this will help you.